# How do I make my navbar clickable or responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

Hey I was just asking how could I make my navbar clickable with icons. My icons wont redirect the page to where I would like it to go, that is what I need help with thanks for the help in advance :D! this is my code:

HTML:

```css
.navbar__link {
    position: static;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
}

// you don't need to add class to a tag, it can be selected by following way
.navbar > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  // make the header take all space of body
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;

  // make navbar take all space that remains after the logo
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;

  // make the navbar move left side else it will not be in complete middlle
  transform: translate(-100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
      <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/company home.png' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar" style="justify-content: center;">
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">search</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

If you do find or know the fix please answer and then edit the code and write fixed under this line

[UPDATE] (FIXED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your `href` attribute in your `a` tags are mostly directing to `#` or `/` instead of a file you want to load. `href` refers to Hypertext Reference, and you put the link of the file/id/class you want to locate in this attribute. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp).

To link your `a` tag to another HTML file, you can just change the `#` or `/` to a path to the HTML file you want. For example:

```
<a href="samplehtml123.html" [other attributes]><span></span></a>
```

The `href="#"` works too, but in this case it redirects to the top of the page because it is just left at `#` and not specified. In general, `#` locates elements with a specific ID in your HTML code. For example, I may have a `p` tag that looks like this:

```
<p id="samplepara">This is some sample text.</p>
```

Then, I can reference this in my `href` attribute:

```
<a href="#samplepara" [other attributes]><span></span></a>
```

When clicking on the icon, I will be directed to an element with such an ID in the web page instead of being directed to another file. IDs are unique to each HTML element and cannot be used twice, hence `href` attribute can redirect to an ID, but not a class. As for `/`, it is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: Let me try this, thank you very much for the answer tho :D!